# Odoo 10: How to pass html element value to Python

Tags: python, html, odoo

I have a Odoo module with Html `<select>` tag, and I want to pass `<option>` value (inside select tag) to Python model and do some stuff with this value.
Can somebody guide me about this?

Xml code:

```
<form>
    <select style="width: 200px" id="dropdown">
            <option value="volvo">Value1</option>
            <option value="saab">Value2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Some of my Python code I'm trying:

```
        @http.route('/my_module/',auth='public')
        def get_ip_address(self,**kw):
            values = http.request.env['my_module.name']
            print values
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to write the select options in a form, and in form action you will get the select value. If you update your question with code, we can help you

```
<form action="/xxxxx" method="POST" id="unique_id">
<select style="width: 200px" id="dropdown">
        <option value="volvo">Value1</option>
        <option value="saab">Value2</option>
</select>
</form>
```

in http controller

```
@http.route(['/xxxx'], type='http', website=True, auth='public')
def func(self,**post):
    print post, "Here Check post values"
```

Working Example Tested:

```
                            <form method="post" action="/website_payment/delete/">
                            <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="delete_pm_id" class="form-control" >
                                    <t t-foreach="pms" t-as="pm">
                                        <option t-att-value="pm.id" t-esc="pm.name"/>
                                    </t>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary">Delete <span class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></span></button>
                        </form>


@http.route(['/website_payment/delete/'], methods=['POST'], type='http', auth="user", website=True)
def delete(self, delete_pm_id=None):
    if delete_pm_id:
        pay_meth = request.env['payment.method'].browse(int(delete_pm_id))
        pay_meth.unlink()
    return request.redirect('/my/payment_method')
```

Comment: I just update my question with Xml code, because in Python I don't know how to get the option values from this Xml. I read in other pages that http.request is possibly necessary, but I'm confused.

Comment: not works, when I run the function I get the following output: {} Here Check post values, but not the selected option value in the dropdown (select tag)

Comment: give name to select fields

Comment: I get an error: "global name 'delete_pm_id' is not defined ('dropdown' in my case)

Comment: you please check the odoo's web login route or check the controller documentation.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is HTML and CSS.

```
<span style="color:red"><b>This is red</b></span>
```

Use [template](http://www.bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#tutorial-templates) to make pages.